# Validate dynamically added control

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How can I add the dynamically added control to validation?

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Middlename)*@
    <div id="x"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement());

            newTextBoxDiv.html('<input type="text" name="Middlename" id="Middlename" width="100" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Middleneim field is required." />');

            newTextBoxDiv.appendTo('#x');
        });

    </script>

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Middlename)
</div>
```

I noticed that when I don't use the ready function, i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement());

newTextBoxDiv.html('<input type="text" name="Middlename" id="Middlename" width="100" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Middleneim field is required." />');

newTextBoxDiv.appendTo('#x');
</script>
```

,the client-side validations kicks-in. Is there a way to explicitly include the deferredly-created inputs to validations?

Comment: would you like to show information about error on the top of the page? if so then you can get MiddleName value and validate it. if it will not valid input then add   ModelState.AddModelError("<give_any_name>", "<error_string>");

Comment: there's no error on top of page, i'm using ASP.NET MVC 3. the default is client-side validation. i'm wondering when I'm not using the jQuery's ready function, everything is normal, i.e. dynamically-added input is no different from design-time added input, it(dynamically-added) is also validated(while the user is typing) if it is Required or not

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: This answer is if you use jquery unobtrusive validation, you did not wrote what you use.

First, add this plugin to jQuery ready:
http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/applying-unobtrusive-validation-to-dynamic-content/

Mind that you must add your element inside of form tag. Lets say that you have some wrapper around your tag, I will call it "element".

After you append your element to DOM, call this:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent($(element).find("form").selector);
var form = $(element).find("form");
$(form).valid();
    $(form).find("input").each(function () {
        $(this).blur(function () {
            $(this).valid();
        });
    });
    $(form).find("select").each(function () {
        $(this).change(function () {
            $(this).valid();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is technically feasible to add to the MVC client side validation by pushing values into the "window.mvcClientValidationMetadata" array of validators. There's a pretty good article [here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html) which shows some of the scripts and techniques involved. This will not help you with server side validation, but as the client won't get this input without javascript you have mitigated this.

I would normally apply a more standard progressive enhancement pattern to this. Create the middle name input by default, and implement standard MVC validators. Then use jQuery to hide it unless (or until) required. Of course this may not fit with your requirements, but if it does, then I'd argue that's a better methodology.